# HTML Image String Parser

Tags: ios, uiwebview, html-parsing

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas for my problem.  I need to extract all the image files from a html file loaded by a UIWebView.  I have the file loaded into a NSString and now need to parse the file.  I have gone through creating an array with componentsSeparatedByString searching for .jpg, .gif, etc.  Then trying to work backwards to get to the beginning of the file.  My best solution would be to be able to parse out the html into an NSArray containing img src="source" width="" height="" etc

Any help or hints would be appreciated.  My last ditch effort would be doing a search/replace left to right of the entire file to find the strings I need, but hope there is a quicker way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse HTML, use [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/).  It has an extensive range of HTML-oriented parsing/traversing functions that let you navigate your document programmatically by elements.

I haven't got HTML-oriented sample code to work from, but it should just be a matter of [`htmlReadDoc()`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html#htmlReadDoc) to get a parsed document; and then adapt your traversal from the [read tree example](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/tree1.c).

```
void print_element_names(xmlNode * a_node)
{
    xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;

    for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) {
        if (cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            printf("node type: Element, name: %s\n", cur_node->name);
        }

        print_element_names(cur_node->children);
    }
}

// ... call your version of this function with the root node of the document
```